# What size Aluminum 3 wire should I use to run 200 feet underground at 100 Amps

Tags: electrical

What size aluminum 3 wire should I use to run 200 feet underground at 100 amps 110/220 volts?  This is in Colorado and will be used to run a mobile home with an electric dryer as the only 220 volt appliance.

Comment: Stove/range is gas? Water heater is gas?

Comment: IS this for the main service to the home, or is it as sub-feed from another structure?

Answer (score 2):

It can only be 3 if this is the service drop - if it's a sub-panel it needs to be 4-wire.

3/0 (000) should do it. There are MANY [voltage drop calculators](http://www.electrician2.com/calculators/vd_calculator.html) on the web, as well as tables/charts. I happen to like the one linked, but they are mostly similar and should all give similar results. Shoot for 3% or less drop at rated (or calculated) load.
 I added 10 feet to account for getting the wire in and out of the ground, rather than just the horizontal distance - wire length, not "as a bird flies" is the number that matters for length.

I prefer to allow for the full load (100 amps) rather than attempting to finesse 30A 240V dryer + 120 volt loads unknown; I've lived with an undersized feed and I'm not fond of self-induced brown-outs.

Comment: If this is for the main service to the home then IMO 3/0, even AL, is a bit big. No need AT ALL to go that large. Knowing the calculated load would be a big help, as opposed to simply using 100A, which is quite unrealistic.