# Running 100 amp service

Tags: electrical

What wire size is needed to run 100 amp service 220 feet with no more than 3% voltage drop? Running a fused disconnect off of meter on house out to detached garage.

Comment: Are you running this feeder overhead, in conduit, or as a direct bury?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93718/what-size-aluminum-3-wire-should-i-use-to-run-200-feet-underground-at-100-amps?rq=1 and http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/74445/what-size-of-wire-do-i-need-to-run-from-200-amp-meter-panel-to-100-amp-sub-panel?rq=1